# Using Parsave inside parfor loop - saves only my last variable result

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

This is a simplified version of my code. What i want to obtain is a variable1 - row vector contained in result.mat. Problem is that parsave - saves only one result, the last one from the 10th iteration. What can i do to save all results in one vector (in variable1) inside the parfor loop?

```
parfor ii = 1:10

    [variable1, variable2] = MyFunction(~,~,ii);

    parsave('result.mat',variable1, variable2)

end

function parsave(filename, varargin)

narginchk(2, Inf);

nargoutchk(0, 0);

for I = 2:nargin

    varname = genvarname(inputname(I));
    eval([varname ' = varargin{' num2str(I-1) '};'])

    if (I == 2)
        save(filename, varname)
    else
        save(filename, varname, '-append')
    end

end
```

Comment: I added 2 tags to attract more attention from the people good with Matlab parallel processing hope that's ok with you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an elegant solution on http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/179884-save-inside-parfor-loop-at-a-specific-iteration-step

```
  parpool('local',10); % results will be distributed on 10 workers

  output1=distributed.NaN(1,1e5); %pre-allocate
  output2=distributed.NaN(1,1e5);

  spmd
   for i=drange(1:1e5)

  [output1(ii), output2(ii)] = MyFunction(~,~,ii);

  parsave(['output1', num2str(labindex)],...
          getLocalPart(output1));
  parsave(['output2', num2str(labindex)],...
              getLocalPart(output2));
   end
  end
```

I've used 2 times the parsave function so in case that the machine shuts down before the simulation ends, 10 mat files will be saved with temporary results that I'll need to concatenate later (for output1 & output2)

The parsave function is:

```
  function parsave(fname,data)

  var_name=genvarname(inputname(2));
  eval([var_name '=data'])

  try
  save(fname,var_name,'-append')
  catch
  save(fname,var_name)
  end

% Written by Minjie Xu (<mailto:chokkyvista06@gmail.com chokkyvista06@gmail.com>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `parsave`, you have the following statement:

```
if (I == 2)
    save(filename, varname)
else
    save(filename, varname, '-append')
end
```

Thus, on your first pass of `parsave`, every time you run `parsave`, you overwrite `filename`.

In addition, your code is a huge risk for a race-condition: Assume two processes try to do the "initial save" of the file at the same time - one is going to overwrite the other, or throws a "cannot access file" error.

You're much better off saving to temp files in the parfor loop, and to follow this up with an aggregator function that combines the different saves into something useful - or simply save into a new directory every time you run the loop, rather than creating a new file.